# In HTML, do ::after and ::before pseudoelements only work with renderable "non-replaced" elements?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I recently noticed on a project that the `::after` pseudoelement did not add any content after an `input` element:

```
input::after { content: "xxxxxxxxxx"; } // no "virtual last child" inserted into DOM "after" the input
```

(reference to "virtual last child" is from MDN page [here](http://The%20CSS%20::after%20pseudo-element%20matches%20a%20virtual%20last%20child%20of%20the%20selected%20element))

Of course, an element such as a div will have content "after" it, and the last child "::after" will be inserted into the DOM:

```
div:empty::after { content: "xxxxxxxxxx"; }

//In DOM
<div>::after</div>
```

but nothing is inserted in these cases:

```
head, script { content: "qaqaqa"; }
```

My initial assumption was that any HTML elements that are rendered by the browser with tags that should be closed (.e.g, p, body, html, div,....etc) will have `::after` inserted as a last child (and `::before` inserted as a first-child), whereas elements that do NOT fit this (e.g., script, head, img, br, input,...etc) will not exhibit this behavior. My CodePen attempts suggested this was correct.

I read through documentation which finally led me to [this resource](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html), in which a note reads:

```
 Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction 
       of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). 
       This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.
```

(for definition of "replaced elements" see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element))

So now my **refined assumption** regarding `::after` and `::before` is that these pseudoelements are only applicable to "renderable" elements which cannot be classified as "replaced elements" (Note this refined assumption now excludes `textarea` from use with `::after` / `::before`, whereas my initial assumption would have *included* it - `textarea::after` was tested with CodePen and no `::after` last child is inserted into the DOM).

Would the **refined assumption** be correct?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML does not define which elements are replaced elements or which elements can contain `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. Neither do CSS2.1 or selectors-3. The latest rewrite of [css-content-3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#content-property), however, states pretty unambiguously:

> Replaced elements do not have '::before' and '::after' pseudo-elements

although implementations of course are not consistent with the draft (famously or otherwise, WebKit/Blink) since this wasn't hitherto defined.

Whether an element can have `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements is not defined by its content model (i.e. if it's void or otherwise), or whether it has an end tag, in HTML. And again, a lot of this is implementation-dependent. For example, some implementations allow `br` of all things to have `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, because nobody knows exactly how `br` is supposed to be implemented in terms of CSS and each browser does it its own way (because neither HTML nor CSS actually defines this).

A `head` element and any of its descendants *can* have `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements — all you have to do is change their `display` to something other than `none`. Obviously, they're not supposed to be displayed, but that doesn't stop anyone trying to be clever.

As far as CSS is concerned, `input` and `textarea` are both considered replaced elements, even though `textarea` has a start tag, end tag, and content. Whether these elements *should* or *must* be replaced elements is not stated (not even in [section 14.5 of WHATWG HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#widgets)), but most browsers render them as replaced elements by default, and this behavior usually can't be changed. And for the purposes of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements not being supported, that's all that matters.

Comment: OK, makes sense - after I set head { display : inline ; } with head::after {content: "xxxx" ;} I saw that the ::after last child was inserted into the DOM for the <head> tag -- but not until I explicitly set display:inline

Comment: same behavior observed for <script>

Answer (score 0):

Don't guess, read: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#gen-content

> The ::before and ::after pseudo-elements can be used to describe generated content before or after an element's content.

`input` has no content, so no `after` element is shown. Same applies for every HTML element with no content (`br`, `menuitem`, `link`...). All auto-closing tags have no content, and some others (like `script`) have none too.

Comment: A valid textarea such as this ---> <textarea>xxxxx</textarea> has content, but does not work with ::after/::before

Comment: I can't find the appropriate part of the spec, but pseudo-elements are rendered as HTML elements, therefore they can only be present in elements that can contain descendant HTML elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas, when I set a script tag to have display:inline and set a rule ---> script::after {content:"xxxxxx";}, the pseudo-element is in the DOM. Shouldn't <script> be w/o descendants?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob `script` is fallen back to a text node (as in old browsers which do not recognized it), so I *guess* (that's where I should check specs and such) its content is considered as a normal text node and hidden by default (so shown if you set `display:inline`, and so it accepts `::after` and `::before` elements).